# Python difference two dictionaries by one uniq key

Tags: python, python-3.x, difference

Need add to database only difference data_out - database.

---

How to add to database only news from data_out (regular refresh), and database not have this data?
in db must be without duplicates!

---

```
database = [ 
{ id: 1, name: 'steve', age: '18'},
{ id: 2, name: 'margo', age: '17'},
{ id: 3, name: 'sten', age: '19'}
 ]

data_from_out = [ 
{ name: 'steve', age: '18'},
{ name: 'margo', age: '17'},
{ name: 'sten', age: '19'},
{ name: 'janifer', age: '21'},
{ name: 'mary', age: '21'}
 ]
```

Diff by name/title (this uniq param), and add to DB only diff.

add to DB  =>

```
{ "name": 'janifer', "age": '21'},
{ "name": 'mary', "age": '21'}
.
```

---

```
def compare_diff(arr_in, arr_database, check_tag):
    try:
        db_records = {d[check_tag] for d in arr_database}
        data_from_out_records = {d[check_tag] for d in arr_in}

        # set difference
        diff = data_from_out_records - data_from_out_records & db_records

        # make array from diff set
        diff = [d for d in data_from_out_records if d[check_tag] if diff]

        return diff

    except:
        print('Error in compare_diff. File file.py.')
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, it is very unclear what you are asking. Also please include code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` you are describing is the set difference between `data_from_out_records` and `db_records`

```
db_records = {d["name"] for d in database}
data_from_out_records = {d["name"] for d in data_from_out}
diff = data_from_out_records - data_from_out_records & db_records
diff = [d for d in data_from_out if d["name"] if diff]
```

Comment: need compare only by name

Comment: Even easier, fixed it.
 If my answer was helpful please accept it or at least vote up

Comment: print(diff) # set()
need return json array

Comment: look to UPD in question. Error in compare_diff. File func.py.
P.S: and to json file did writes "null"

Comment: diff = [d for d in data_from_out if d["name"] if diff] = NONE!

Answer (score 0):

work code =>

```
def compare_diff(arr_in, arr_database, check_tag):
    try:
        db_records = {d[check_tag] for d in arr_database}
        data_from_out_records = {d[check_tag] for d in arr_in}

        # set difference
        diff = data_from_out_records - (data_from_out_records & db_records)

        # make array from diff set
        diff_arr = [d for d in arr_in if d[check_tag] in diff]

        return diff_arr

    except:
        print('Error in compare_diff')
        return False
```

thanks @Uri-Goren for the help.